# EF TPT tries to map to single table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a base table ChangeLog, and two derived tables BillOfQuantitiesChangeLogMap and ProjectChangeLogMap:

```
CREATE TABLE [Global].[ChangeLogs](
   [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [FieldName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [OldValue] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
   [NewValue] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
   ...

CREATE TABLE [Projects].[BillOfQuantitiesChangeLogs](
   [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   [ExtraField] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
   ...

CREATE TABLE [Projects].[ProjectChangeLogMap](
   [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
   ...
```

They are added to the dbcontext as follows:

```
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChangeLogMap());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BillOfQuantitiesChangeLogMap());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjectChangeLogMap());
```

...which are all defined in the same way, for example:

```
public class ChangeLogMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChangeLog>
{
    public ChangeLogMap()
    {
        ToTable("ChangeLogs", "Global");

        Property(t => t.FieldName)
            .IsRequired();
        Property(t => t.OldValue);
        Property(t => t.NewValue);
    }
}
```

The derived entity inherits from the base entity:

```
public class BillOfQuantitiesChangeLog : ChangeLog
{
   ...
}
```

When we now save a BillOfQuantitiesChangeLog instance, it all works fine.

However, when in the dbcontext we only add two mappings, like:

```
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChangeLogMap());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BillOfQuantitiesChangeLogMap());
```

... then saving a BillOfQuantitiesChangeLog results in an error message that 'ExtraField' could not be found. So I guess it tries to map BillOfQuantitiesChangeLog to a single table instead of to two tables.

My question is: why does EF not apply TPT if we add only one mapping of a derived class to the context?

Comment: TPH stands for *Table per Hierarchy*. This means all hierarchical objects mapped to one table. Are you trying to achieve TPC or TPT?

Comment: Sorry, no, needs to be separate tables. One for the base type and one for each derived type. So TPT. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a TPT mapping simply by placing Table attribute on the subclasses to specify the mapped table name

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<BillOfQuantitiesChangeLog>().ToTable("BillOfQuantitiesChangeLog");
 modelBuilder.Entity<CreditCard>().ToTable("CreditCards");
```

You can see full documentation here https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt

Comment: But we have already added the ToTable in the mappings, see the ChangeLogMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ChangeLog> in the example...

Comment: you need to map **every derived type to a table** to achieve TPT. Entity framework's default behavior is TPH that's why when you don't map the derived types, you get the TPH relatıons

Comment: So you need to map all derived tables, in order for TPT to work. Thanks!

Comment: @L-Four yes, let me know if you struggle while implementing it and I can improve my answer.

Comment: It was working, I was just wondering why it did not work if we did not add all mappings.